# Get Jekyll to work with existing Github Pages site

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages, cname

I have an existing Github pages site with content on it. I want to add Jekyll blogging functionality to this site but I don't want to get rid of the content I already have on the site. Ideally I'd like to keep my index.html file the way it is and add a subdomain for the Jekyll blog.

Here is [my site](https://nicknyr.github.io/) as is. Here is the [Githu repo](https://github.com/Nicknyr/Nicknyr.github.io) for the site.

I installed Jekyll just fine, created a new blog via Jekyll/terminal, and that blog is located in the Github repo's blog folder. This folder appears to have everything needed to launch a Jekyll blog and I can view it via localhost:4000 and it diplays the Jekyll welcome screen.

My question is how do I get this Jekyll blog to work with the Github pages site I already have? All the tutorials I find online show how to start an empty Github Pages site and use Jekyll as the main page. I can't find a single tutorial on how to add Jekyll to an existing Github Pages site and get it to work.

Is this a matter of configuring a CNAME or config.yml file?

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure I'm understanding you correctly, your site is `nicknyr.github.io` and you said you wanted your blog as a ***subdomain***, (something like `blog.nicknyr.github.io`).

You need to put your Jekyll blog in a separate repo from the `nicknyr.github.io` repo. In the Jekyll repo, put a `CNAME` file at the root directory with the contents being the name of the url you want it to have `blog.nicknyr.github.io`. It's important to leave out the `http(s)://` part!

Then, in your repo settings under "Options"->"GitHub Pages", set the custom domain to `blog.nicknyr.github.io`.

---

If you meant that your blog would be a ***subdirectory*** `nicknyr.github.io/blog`, I don't think that's possible without funky redirects and a custom subdomain. The repo serving the domain `nicknyr.github.io` is responsible for serving all subdirectories of that domain. It's possible, but takes a lot more manual manipulation. At that point, you might be better off putting the blog in the same repo and setting the Jekyll output into a specific folder to be displayed on the frontend.

Answer (score 0):

This post helped me figure out what was wrong with my setup, and I was able to get it working.

Posting it here in case it helps anyone else: https://ellatronic.com/blog/blog/2015/12/2/setting-up-a-custom-subdomain-with-github-user-pages-and-namecheap

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what @DC.Azndj said, you can add Jekyll as part of the subdirectory (e. g. `username.github.io/blog`) adding `baseurl: "/blog"` in `_config.yml`.

[Here is a more detailed description by Kilt and Code](https://www.kiltandcode.com/2020/04/30/how-to-create-a-blog-using-jekyll-and-github-pages-on-windows/).